# Creating lists from huge object taking more time than creating it from huge file

Tags: python, file, object, optimization

I was working with a huge file today when I found this. My mind = blown, till now I always used to create a single in memory object from file and used to do all my stuff on that object.

Consider this use case where I am creating a huge file (for clarity sake) and then reading it into 2 different lists.

```
import csv
import time

TEMP_FILE_NAME = '/tmp/foo.csv'   

def write_huge_file():
    with open(TEMP_FILE_NAME, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows((((i, i + 100) for i in xrange(29999999))))

def get_file_iterator():
    with open(TEMP_FILE_NAME, 'rb') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            yield row

def make_2_list_from_object():
    file_iterator = get_file_iterator()
    main_list = [(i, j) for i, j in file_iterator]
    list1 = [i[0] for i in main_list]
    list2 = [i[1] for i in main_list]

def make_2_list_from_file():
    list1 = list(i[0] for i in get_file_iterator())
    list2 = list(i[1] for i in get_file_iterator())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #write_huge_file()   # Uncomment this to write the file once
    print 'wrote_file'
    a = time.time()
    make_2_list_from_file()
    b = time.time()
    print b-a
    make_2_list_from_object()
    c = time.time()
    print 'Time taken using file: ', str(b-a)
    print 'Time taken using object: ', str(c-b)
```

Now when I run it I get this output:

```
Time taken using file:    49.212211132 s
Time taken using object:  1018.5052530766 s
```

Can anyone please explain this to me? I am thinking its because of python's swap memory usage when it runs out of RAM.

Also please note that I had 4 Gigs of RAM while running this program. You can increase the number of lines in written file if you have more RAM to reproduce this.

Comment: It's a bad idea to post your email address in the question of the post (nor does it add any value to the question). I've removed it for you in this question.

Comment: Oops sorry, It came in as a snippet in vim :/

Comment: For smaller files, I get the reverse timing, i.e. using an intermediate list is fast. This would suggest that you exhaust your memory :)

Comment: Yeah..I found that too. Thats why I emphasized on the file to be huge :)

Comment: One would have to use system-specific means to measure swap space usage or file system accesses to further support this highly likely explanation.